Issues when using dompurify.sanitize method on Veracode report for Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability
I am Facing Cross-Site Scripting(XSS) issues in Vera code report. I was using dompurify.sanitize() method and also allowed its attributes. Earlier when I was using this method on my code it was fixed but it again shows Cross-Site Scripting(XSS) issues in Vera code report. At Now When I am removing attribute from dompurify.sanitize() then ,Cross-Site Scripting(XSS) issues doesn't appear on report. I have struck on these issues please give me suggestion for this.
Implement dompurify with allow attribute:- childNode.innerHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(response, {ADD_ATTR: ['onclick']});
Remove attribute from dompurify :- childNode.innerHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(response);
I am expecting solution for the above issues.
